# Wordpress Static front page on all themes

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I recently noticed some wordpress themes don't support custom static front pages instead of the blog page.
For example: The theme "Twenty Eleven" https://fuc.wordpress.org/themes/twentyeleven/

Is it possible to change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

Make a page name front-page.php in the theme's folder and then in Wordpress Admin Settings change the frontpage from "Your latest posts" to Static Frontpage.

Documentation Here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page